# synchronising between threads handling read and write in sockets with infinite loops

Tags: multithreading, sockets, mutex

I am doing a task to receive user input in one thread (thread 1) and another thread(thread 2) to send cyclic CAN messages on a linux environment. The flow of the program is as follows,

1. In main thread, created a socket using `socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0)` for server-client TCP connection
2. Bind was successfully done.
3. Using `accept()`, server-client established
4. Upon 3) , two threads are created, thread1 and thread2
5. thread 1 for user input from `recv()`, http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/recv.2.html
6. thread 2 created socket for CAN communication using *socket* and uses timer to send the CAN messages with specified interval, continuously.

In thread2, I have used `timer_create` to send cyclic messages, which uses `write` function to write the CAN messages in the *CAN socket*.
http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/timer_create.2.html

The problem is I have `recv` in an infinite loop in thread1 waiting for user input and the timer function in thread2 is also continuous. This makes `recv` to exit with signal interruption `EINTR` from thread1. I have tried the following,

- Created a condition wait using `pthread_cond_wait` in thread 1, to wait for status update from thread 2. This does not work, as once the timer has started, it does not check for condition variable any more.

Does anyone has similar experience with using socket in two infinite loops for receiving and sending in two threads and controlling it on a condition variable. Any suggestion on how to handle them?

Comment: "This makes recv to exit with EINTR" So? Why is that a problem?

Comment: Exactly. Just `continue` on EINTR in thread 1.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback . If *recv()* is interrupted , user input is disconnected . Using *continue* if EINTR occurred would be problematic if I want to end the execution using ctrl +c . Also it will be interrupted many times and reconnected since thread 2 will be continuous with timer function. Is it possible to suspend the thread 2 when *recv* gets input . I tried that with condition variable *pthread_cond_wait* as I discussed above .

Comment: @Aksh Ctrl+C will terminate the process if you don't set special handling for it. If you do, you should handle it separately. For example by setting some global flag and checking it after `recv` returns. It is _really_ hard to say anything without the code, your explanations are not clear enough.

Comment: @StaceyGirl Thanks for your message. And sorry for the late reply. I found the error to be when slow system calls like _accept()_, _read()_ etc., are made in multiple threads, they may get interrupted and need to use **SA_RESTART** in a _sigaction()_. I am still figuring out how to use them . Thanks for your reply anyways. Any suggestion or link on the same is much appreciated.

Comment: I just found out that `SA_RESTART` does not work with EITNR in case of `accept()` , `recv()` from [link](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html). I will post a new question with the working code. Thank you!